# error 404 al recargar mi aplicativo web Angular en un servidor Dongee

Tags: angular, cpanel

subí mi aplicativo Web hecho en Angular, a un servidor Dongee Cpanel, pero al momento de recargar la pagina o de presionar F5 esta me da un error 404 y no se que configuración le debo realizar a mi servidor.
para que realice la prueba dejo el link del aplicativo

https://frontend.mercurylab.com.co/login

Comment: Si es un servidor apache, hay que hacer unas cuantes configuraciones a htaccess, que ahora no tengo a la mano. Busca en google y encontraras esas opciones.

Comment: Prueba esto https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator, se ve interesante.

Comment: si me sirvo tu información muchas gracias